# Format a 'numeric' string as a number

Tags: clojure

I would like to format a 'numeric' string as a 'string number' in Clojure. This is the format mask:

> "#,###,###,##0.00"

Given the string "9999.99" I would expect to receive back "9,999.99".

How would I do this in Clojure without resorting to writing a converter function i.e. using `format` or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `,` in a format specifier:

```
(format "%,.2f" (float (clojure.edn/read-string "9999")))
=> "9,999.00"
(format "%,.2f" (Double/parseDouble "9999.126"))
=> "9,999.13"
```

Update to include `bigdec` example:

```
(format "%,.2f" (bigdec "9999999999999999.12"))
=> "9,999,999,999,999,999.12"
```

Comment: (format "%,.2f" (Double/parseDouble "9999999999999999.12")) gives "10,000,000,000,000,000.00" and (format "%,.2f" (float (clojure.edn/read-string "9999999999999999.12"))) is worse at "10,000,000,272,564,224.00". The intervening use of float/double will loose precision.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that in your problem domain the disadvantages and limitations of binary-base floating point (e.g. IEEE-754) are causing you some difficulty. Perhaps you should consider taking advantage of the BigDecimal support already built in to Clojure. In Clojure, the difference between a BigDecimal constant and a floating point constant is a single character; e.g. 1.2 is a Double, while 1.2M is a BigDecimal. The `bigdec` function can be used to convert things to BigDecimal on the fly. For example,

```
(format "%,.2f" (bigdec "9999999999999999.12"))
```

produces

```
"9,999,999,999,999,999.12"
```

as expected. Arithmetic functions such as `*`, `+`, `-`, and `/` also work as expected.

However, this doesn't solve your basic problem. If your format string doesn't follow Java/Clojure format string conventions you'll have to write a converter function.

Best of luck.

Comment: I know that `format` is an inherited function. But it would be a lot better if it just accepted a string as input. I'm using `org.joda.money` on the server and wanting to do some formatting for presentation in the browser.

Comment: The conventions the format string follows are not really important to the question, just easier/shorter to use it rather than to describe the required output in words.

Comment: Are you then using ClojureScript in the browser?

Comment: Yes I am, ClojureScript/Fulcro in the the browser and Clojure/Fulcro (which includes Ring) on the back-end.

Comment: Why do you ask? I'm now actually not doing the translation from string->string but from the underlying BigDecimal in org.joda.money ->string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `NumberFormat`.  I also like the other answer (see [the Java 10 `Formatter` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for details):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:import [java.text NumberFormat]
           [java.util Locale]))

(dotest
  (let [value (Double/valueOf "1234567.89")
        nf    (NumberFormat/getNumberInstance (Locale/US))
        s1a   (.format nf (.doubleValue value))
        s1b   (format "%,05.2f" value)]
    (spyx s1a)
    (spyx s1b))

s1a => "1,234,567.89"
s1b => "1,234,567.89"

  (let [value (Double/valueOf "1.2")
        nf    (NumberFormat/getNumberInstance (Locale/US))
        s1a   (.format nf (.doubleValue value))
        s1b   (format "%,05.2f" value)]
    (spyx s1a)
    (spyx s1b)))

s1a => "1.2"
s1b => "01.20"
```

---

## Update

Here is how to do it for BigDecimal, using first Java interop and then a built-in Clojure function `bigdec`:

```
(format "%,05.2f" (BigDecimal. "9999999999999999.12")) => "9,999,999,999,999,999.12"
(format "%,05.2f" (bigdec      "9999999999999999.12")) => "9,999,999,999,999,999.12"
```

Comment: There is a Clojure function called `bigdec` you can use instead of resorting to interop.